# Custom mint account keypair use cases

Tags: web3.js, vanity-id

[#2516](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/2516) added a way to specify a custom keypair for mint accounts.

Besides having a cool looking mint account address, are there any other use cases for custom keypairs? What could someone do with a mint account's secret key? Are there any security implications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mainly for vanity public keys.

The mint account itself will never sign for any instruction/transaction, so, similar to programs, while its best not to discard or make the keypair publicly visible, not much can be done. The operations surrounding a mint and managing its supply are locked to the mint and freeze authorities of the mint instead.

Comment: I would add that it's a pretty good idea to hold onto the private key just in case someone accidentally creates a token account owned by your mint and sends tokens there. For example, the USDT mint address `Es9vMFrzaCERmJfrF4H2FYD4KCoNkY11McCe8BenwNYB` owns *a lot* of tokens.